# Update table dates using cxDateEdit

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi

I am trying to update all dates in my table with the value of cxDateEdit1 as the main parameter. I try and run :

```
UNIQuery2.sql.Clear;
UNIquery2.sql.Text:='UPDATE TEMP SET DATE = cxDateEdit1.Date';
UNIQuery2.execsql;
```

But it wont work. Any ideas as to why it does not work ?

The error I get is this :

> no such column: cxDateEdit1.Date.

Comment: "wont work" is not a valid description. You should have an error message you can copypaste here (CTRL-C when error message is shown and CTRL-V here)

Comment: There is no need to paste the message as an image. Just press CRTL-C when the window is active and the whole text is copied to clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include the name of your components inside an SQL statement.  Try something like this (not sure of the type and exact syntax for UNIQuery2):

```
UNIQuery2.sql.Clear;
UNIquery2.sql.Text := 'UPDATE TEMP SET DATE = :Date';
UNIquery2.ParamByName('Date').AsDateTime := cxDateEdit1.Date;
UNIQuery2.Execsql;
```